# Why do I need to use @Validated in my class to get expected errors with @Positive?

Tags: spring, spring-validator

I have this method:

```
@GetMapping
 public List<BudgetForecastApi> findByHotel(@PathVariable @Positive final int hotelCode,
@RequestParam(value = "includeDeleted", defaultValue = "false") final Boolean includeDeleted) {
 
     return this.getService.findByHotel(hotelCode, includeDeleted);
 }
```

and when I make an HTTP Request I get this error:

> {
> "id": "65dd4914-ddda-43c2-b204-b0a3e9279635",
> "code": "HTL-1",
> "date": "2023-11-16T14:59:30.44724275",
> "httpStatus": 400,
> "httpErrorMessage": "Bad Request",
> "message": "Service exception: Hotel configuration not found"
> }

But what I'm expecting is for the @Positive annotation to generate an error. And that only happens if I add a @Validated annotation at class level.

This is the error I get when I do that:

> {
> "id": "c2ad2ba6-c51f-4132-8394-fbacd40655d0",
> "code": "API-04",
> "date": "2023-11-16T15:13:50.57191511",
> "httpStatus": 400,
> "httpErrorMessage": "Bad Request",
> "message": "Validation error: hotelCode must be greater than 0, budgetForecastId must not be blank"
> }

What I am asking is why? why do I need @Validated? I didn't before. I'm confused and haven't found anything in the docs saying I'm required to use @Validated to trigger the rest of annotations.

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to validate single arguments with Validation API you need `@Validated` to proxy this. If you want to validate a nested object (one that binds the parameters or request body) you can use `@Valid` on the object.

Comment: so the use of Validated is required to enable validation on method parameters? Can you give me a link to the documentation where it says that? I didn't need Validated before do you know why I do now?

Comment: It is needed for validating simply things (so `@PathVariable` or `@RequestParam`/`@RequestHeader` in your method) instead bound objects, that has been always the case.